# Windows IIS does not send a close_notify?

Tags: c, ssl, iis, openssl

When I do a SSL_Connect and afterwards a SSL_Shutdown(), the Windows IIS does not respond with a close_notify while Apache and Nginx do. The code to test this is out is down below and the pictures of the Wireshark is at the bottom.

If I comment out the SSL_Read for the IIS since it doesn't send anything the IIS would send a TCP RST. Apache would do this as well if the SSL_Read was commented out.

But in Windows IIS if I do a GET request before SSL_Shutdown it would still not send a close_notify but it wouldn't send a TCP RST when I close the connection.

So why does the Windows IIS not send a close notify?

IPs:

- Client: 10.1
- Apache: 12.1
- IIS: 13.1

  ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <unistd.h>

   #include <openssl/ssl.h>
   #include <openssl/err.h>
   #include <sys/socket.h>
   #include <netinet/in.h>
   #include <arpa/inet.h>

   #define SERVER_IP "xxx.xxx.12.3"
   #define SERVER_PORT 443

   // Can be used by wireshark
   void keylog_callback(const SSL *ssl, const char *line)
   {
       const char *keylog_filepath = getenv("SSLKEYLOGFILE");

       FILE *keylog = fopen(keylog_filepath, "a");

       fprintf(keylog, "%s\n", line);
       fclose(keylog);
   }

   int main() {
       SSL_CTX *ctx;
       SSL *ssl;
       int sockfd;
       struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
       char buffer[1024] = {0};

       // Initialize SSL
       SSL_library_init();
       OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
       SSL_load_error_strings();
       ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
       if (ctx == NULL) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Error creating SSL context\n");
           return 1;
       }

       setenv("SSLKEYLOGFILE", "./keylog", 1);
       printf("SSLKEYLOGFILE set to: %s\n", getenv("SSLKEYLOGFILE"));
       SSL_CTX_set_keylog_callback(ctx, keylog_callback);

       // Create socket
       if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
           perror("Socket creation failed");
           return 1;
       }

       // Set server address
       memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
       serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
       serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
       if (inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_IP, &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
           perror("Invalid address/ Address not supported");
           return 1;
       }

       // Connect to server
       if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
           perror("Connection failed");
           return 1;
       }

       // Attach SSL to the socket
       ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
       SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd);
       if (SSL_connect(ssl) <= 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "SSL connection failed\n");
           return 1;
       }

       // Send close notify
       int ret = SSL_shutdown(ssl);

       if (ret==1){   
           printf("Shutdown is done\n");
           SSL_free(ssl);
           close(sockfd);
           SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
           return 0;
       }
       // Shutdown is not finished
       else if (ret == 0){
           printf("Shutdown not finished\n");
           // If I connect to IIS, IIS won't send anything
           // Since SSL_read is blocking it would get stuck here.
           // We would read Apache's close notify here
           SSL_read(ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
           SSL_free(ssl);
           close(sockfd);
           SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
           return 0;
       }
       // Shutdown failed
       else{ 
           printf("Shutdown failed\n");
           SSL_free(ssl);
           close(sockfd);
           SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
           return 0; 
       }
   }
  ```

Set the IP: **#define SERVER_IP "xxx.xxx.12.3"**

Set the keylog file path: **setenv("SSLKEYLOGFILE", "./keylog", 1);**

Apache:
[image: Apache]

Windows IIS:
[image: Windows IIS]

Comment: The screenshot with IIS currently does not show a TCP connection close. So there might still be a close_notify before the TCP close, which you don't show. Please provide a more complete screenshot.

Comment: There is no TCP close because the program is stuck on SSL_Read. If I were to uncomment the SSL_Read the Windows IIS would simply send a TCP RST and would not send a close_notify.



It is stuck on SSL_Read because the IIS didn't send the close_notify while on apache it sends it.

Comment: I see. I think your code is simply doing something which is not expected by a web server: not sending a HTTP request, not closing the TCP connection but only doing a SSL shutdown immediately after TLS handshake and then keep the TCP connection open. And what you get for this unexpected behavior on your part is unexpected behavior on the servers part. Functionality is about implementing expecting behavior properly only, not handling unexpected behavior in a consistent way.

Comment: Like I commented earlier in a similar question, this really is up to the interpretation of the IETF RFC documents. For example, RFC5246 says "Either party **may initiate** a close by sending a close_notify alert. Any data received after a closure alert is ignored" which uses the term of "may" instead of "must/should". If you are familiar with RFC 2119, you know that this statement literally allows close_notify to be absent. In other words, IIS is still standard compliant.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for answering again, I posted it again to give a "Minimal, Reproducible Example". 

As for the RFC 5246 it says: "Unless some other fatal alert ... **each party is required to send a close_notify alert** before closing the write side of the connection.  **The other party MUST respond with a close_notify alert of its own** and close down the connection immediately,... . _It is not required for the initiator of the close to wait for the responding close_notify_ alert before closing the read side of the connection."
So IIS **MUST** respond with a close notify, but it doesn't.

Comment: What you have mentioned there is about **initiating** the close_notify. And that is logical that either party may initiate to close the connection. But according to the RFC onece the close_notify is initiated the other party must respond with a close_notify. Otherwise it is not fully compliant with the RFC.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.